# Use PullToRefresh Plugin

Tags: javascript, cordova, sencha-touch-2

ust started using Sencha Touch 2 and need to integrate https://github.com/j-mcnally/Sencha2-PullToRefresh

I've just started using Sencha, and wasn't able to find in the documentation where to drop in and reference such extensions. What's the file structure and reference code necessary to do so? Does it just go anywhere and I reference it in app.js?

copy the plugins folder to my project and include the js file in index.html

but showing error 
 undefined is not a function
failed to load the RefreshableList.js

Comment: Did the answer below fix your problem. If yes, then accept it, otherwise tell us what did not work and what error you got.

Answer (score 0):

You can find good examples in the **examples** folder of Sencha Touch 2.

There is a good example of the [Pull To Refresh plugin](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.plugin.PullRefresh) in **YOUR_SENCHA_TOUCH_FOLDER/examples/touchtweets/app/view/TweetList.js**

Twitter.view.TweetList extends a list and has the following code in its config :

```
...
plugins: [
    'pullrefresh',
    {
        type: 'listpaging',
        autoPaging: true
    }
],
...
```

Also you need to require the relevant file like so :

```
requires: [
    'Ext.plugin.PullRefresh',
],
```

Hope this helps

Comment: ,Here am parsing the json and displaying only 100 items at a time so after listing 100 items and when the user scroll and reach 100th item , I want to again  parse json .In pullrefresh plugin only while scrolling up refreshFn will call but i want to parse json while scrolling down .

Comment: Then you need the ListPaging plugin : http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.plugin.ListPaging

Answer (score 0):

Sencha Touch 2 provides a pull to refresh plugin, maybe you could use that one? The documentation on the pull to refresh plugin provided by Sencha is at http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.plugin.PullRefresh

Comment: ,Here am parsing the json and displaying only 100 items at a time so after listing 100 items and when the user scroll and reach 100th item , I want to again  parse json .In pullrefresh plugin only while scrolling up refreshFn will call but i want to parse json while scrolling down .

Comment: wouldn't know how to do that, but maybe you could add a listitem to the end of your list containing a button to 'load more items'? I've seen this approach in several apps.